# Who are the rest two Metahuman characters referred in Dawn of Justice?

Tags: dc, character-identification, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

While the 'metahumans' Wonder Woman and Flash are quite easily identifiable even for people like me, not knowing the comics nor the Arrow and Flash  TV series, I would like to know who the other two are?

Comment: Related: [Who are the other three superheroes in Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/50906/49)

Answer (score 3):

Those two metahuman/superhero are:

- [Victor Stone / Cyborg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyborg_(comics)) (played by Ray Fisher): A boy whose partial remaining body got attached with mother box to make him cyborg.

  [image]

On the top right there is partial remaining body of  Victore stone and on the right bottom is the [Mother Box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mother_Box) which is responsible in his creation in comics and in [animated film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League:_War).

- [Arthur Curry / Aquaman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquaman) (played by Jason Momoa): The man under the sea.

  [image]

---

Copied from [my own answer on Movies and TV Stack Exchange](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/50907/1190) for the similar question.